# Merge Data From Multiple Sheets Onto 1 Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm in the process of creating a script that'll merge data from multiple Google sheets onto one.

As I'm new to this, I'm having trouble figuring out an error I keep getting.
It states 'Exception: Range not found' in line 26 of the script.

I'm assuming, maybe incorrectly that there's something wrong with the range I'm using in my variables as to which data to merge onto the main sheet. But changing that doesn't seem to help.

Any tips, advice, or things to try is greatly appreciated.

Here's a link to the sheets.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hv9zANMWzDBpKDWQ3hbDjX4nezEtOoptFbY0PYn_c5Y/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the code for the script.

function

```
    myFunction() {
    //FILTER({'Workout1'}) !E15:AA26,"DATA TAB 1 - ROW             "&ROW('Workout1'!E15:E26)},'Workout1'!E15:E26<>"");
//FILTER({'Workout2'}) !E15:AA26,"DATA TAB 2 - ROW "&ROW('Workout2'!E15:E26)},'Workout2'!E15:E26<>"");
//FILTER({'Workout3'}) !E15:AA26,"DATA TAB 3 - ROW "&ROW('Workout3'!E15:E26)},'Workout3'!E15:E26"");
//FILTER({'Workout1'}) !E15:AA26,"DATA TAB 1 - ROW "&ROW('Workout1'!E15:E26)},'Workout1'!E15:E26<>"");
//setvariables
const masterSheet = "Data";
const ignoreSheets = ["Dashboard"];
const dataRange = "E15:AA26";
const checkRange = "E15:E26";
//end set variables
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
const allsheets = ss.getSheets();
const filteredlistofsheets = allsheets.filter(s => ignoreSheets.indexOf(s.getSheetName()) == -1);

let formulaArray = filteredlistofsheets.map(s => `FILTER({'${s.getSheetName()}'$!{datarange},"${s.getSheetName()} - ROW "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}!${checkRange},ROW "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRange}<>"")`);
let formulaText = "={" + formulaArray.join(";") + "}";

ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange("masterSheetFormulaCell").setformula(formulaText);
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: About your error message of `Exception: Range not found`, in your script, what is `masterSheetFormulaCell` of `ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange("masterSheetFormulaCell").setformula(formulaText);`? I'm worried that this might be related to your current issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without scripts using [REDUCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597?hl=en).

```
=QUERY(
  REDUCE({0,0,0,0}, 
         {"Workout1",
          "Workout2",
          "Workout3"},
          LAMBDA(acc,cur, 
                {acc;
                 INDIRECT(cur&"!E15:E26"),
                 BYROW(INDIRECT(cur&"!K15:O26"),LAMBDA(row,IFERROR(AVERAGE(row)))),
                 BYROW(INDIRECT(cur&"!Q15:U26"),LAMBDA(row,IFERROR(AVERAGE(row)))),
                 BYROW(INDIRECT(cur&"!W15:AA26"),LAMBDA(row,IFERROR(AVERAGE(row))))})
  ),
  "select Col1, 
   sum(Col2), 
   sum(Col3), 
   avg(Col4)
   where Col1 is not null
   group by Col1 
   label Col1 'Exercise', 
         sum(Col2) 'Reps For Each Set',
         sum(Col3) 'Weight Per Set (lbs.)',
         avg(Col4) 'Rest Between Sets (sec.)'",1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mergeAllToFirst() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet ID");
  let sht;
  ss.getSheets().forEach((sh, i) => {
    if (i == 0) {
      sh.clearContents()
      sht = sh;
    } else {
      let vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
      sht.getRange(sht.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(sh.getName());
      sht.getRange(sht.getLastRow() + 1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
    }
  })
}
```